# I am having this error in unity and i don't know what's causing it

Tags: unity

[image]
I don't know how it happen this is an endless runner game
The road is 15 on x and 100 on z.
This is happening in android road is a cube with png image as texture it is distorted and turn blue every 2 sec.

Comment: What error is happening?

Comment: Hi Abhishek. As Tyyppi_77 notes, it's not immediately obvious to an outsider what the error is in your screenshot. Remember that we've never played your game before, so we don't know what it's supposed to look like when everything is running perfectly. Can you please edit your question to describe the results you're getting, and how they differ from the results you want/expect? Sharing some relevant snippets of code or descriptions of how the relevant objects are set up in the scene hierarchy & inspector can often help a lot too.

Comment: I notice you've made an edit from another account. [Please merge your accounts](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can regain control of the question - letting you edit it, comment on the question and its answers, and accept an answer if you find one that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well the question is not clear but since you are talking about the road I'm 100% sure it's about the blurriness of the texture so you have 2 solution.

1. First go in Quality setting change Anisotropic Filtering from Disable to PerTexture and select your texture change Filter Mode to Trilinear and set the aniso level all the way up
2. You second choice is to go in Quality setting again change Anisotropic Filtering to ForcedOn.

This will get rid of the blurriness of the road texture but note that texture Filtering can take some CPU resources. Hope this will help